# Jquery Slideshow doesn't work

Tags: jquery-animate, slideshow

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentImage = $('#slider div');
var nextImage = $('#slider').find('div').next;
var animation = .animate({'marginLeft' : "-=900px"}):


$(document).ready(function(){
 $(currentImage).click(function(){
     $(currentImage).animate();
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slideshow">
<div id="slider">
     <div id="image">
         <img src="slide1.jpg" height="360px" width="960px">

     </div>
     <div id="image">
         <img src="slide2.jpg" height="360px" width="960px">

     </div>
     <div id="image">
         <img src="slide3.jpg" height="360px" width="960px"> 
     </div>
</div>   

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and CSS

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote,                            pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 }
body {
margin: 0;
}
p {
margin: 0;
}
#slideshow {
width: 100%;
float: left;
}
#slider {
margin: 10px auto;
height: 360px;
width: 900px;
border: 1px solid #999;
overflow: hidden;
}
#slider #image {
height: 360px;
width: 900px;
float: left;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}              


This is a HTML (with Jquery in it) and a CSS file.
```

What i am trying to do is that if you click on an #image, the #image wil animate 900px to the left.
But i have a problem because nothing happen if i click on #image.

Can someone help me?

P.S. I am from the Netherlands, so I apologise if I have bad English.

Comment: First problem : You have 3 divs with same id. You can convert it to class instead of id

Comment: invalid HTML, invalid script ... least the CSS is valid?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot wrong with your script ... try this out:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slideshow">
        <div id="slider">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="slide1.jpg" height="360px" width="960px">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="slide2.jpg" height="360px" width="960px">
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="slide3.jpg" height="360px" width="960px"> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var currentImage = $('#slider').find('div').first(),
                nextImage = currentImage.next();

            currentImage.click(function(){
                $(this).animate({marginLeft:"-=900px"});
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Couple points:

- As was called out, make your images use a `class` instead of an `id` if you want to reuse the name. Multiple elements with the same `id` is invalid HTML.
- You did not close `<div id="slideshow">` ... I added the closing tag.
- Move your script down to the bottom of the body ... this is best practice to improve the speed of page rendering (otherwise the page needs to parse the entire script before displaying any content).
- Your use of `.next()` was incorrect ... it is a function, and all functions are called at bare minimum with open/close parenths.
- You were already caching `#slider div`, so I leveraged that existing cachine when searching for `nextImage` (I applied the `.first()` function because it will get all of the `div`s if you don't filter it somehow.
- Your storage of the animation was ... wrong, in about every way possible. You can store the animation in variable as a function, but only for reuse, and clearly you are not ready for that yet. I moved the animation down to where it should be, which is applied to the element in the `click` event itself.
- When referencing the DOM names in the `.animate()` function, you only need to apply quotation marks if you use the CSS version ('margin-left' instead of marginLeft).

No guarantees that this will do what you think it should do because your CSS is ... too much to handle right now, but at least your HTML and JS will now be valid and you can focus on the problem at hand.